# Differential equations: Substitution choice.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a rather trivial question, but I am missing something.

Consider the differential equation :
$$2\,y'+y\,y''=y'\,^2$$

My first attempt was to work along the substitution $z=y'$ and thus the equation becomes :
$$2\,z+y\,z'=z\,^2$$

Again substituting $w=z^{-1}$ the equation becomes :
$$-w'+\frac{2}{y}w=\frac{1}{y}$$

Which can be solved and worked backwards

But I feel this is a very exhaustive and blind method. I'm certain I'm missing a very simple alternative.

Any insight?

---

EDIT: I've tried going along my line of reasoning.

Solving this equation: $$-w'+\frac{2}{y}w=\frac{1}{y}$$

Using the integrating factor :
$$\rho=\exp{{\int{-\frac{2}{y}}dy}}=\dots=\frac{1}{y^2}$$ taking the constant to be $0$.

Thus $w$ is given by :
$$w = \frac{1}{y^2}\int\rho\,\frac{1}{y}\,dy = y^2(\frac{-4}{y^4}+c_1)$$

Reversing the substitution :
$$z^{-1}=\frac{-4}{y^2}+c_1y^2$$

And again :
$$y' = (\frac{-4}{y^2}+c_1y^2)^{-1}$$
$$(\frac{-4}{y^2}+c_1y^2)dy = dx$$
$$\frac{12}{y^3}+\frac{c_1}{3}y^3+c_2=x$$

Thus the solution reduces to the implicit form :

$$\frac{12}{y^3}+k_1y^3+k_2=x$$

Can somebody verify/comment on my line of reasoning?

Comment: It seems there's an error in the last line, which should read $$-w' + \frac{2}{y}w = \frac{1}{y}$$

Comment: By inspection something like $e^x$ might work and is fairly easy to see that $e^x-2$ does work, and indeed $Ae^x-2$ works just as well. But one also cannot help wondering how to get $e^{kx}$ to work. This is harder, but with some playing around I got $Ae^{kx}-\frac{2}{k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This type of ODE can be put into the form: $y''=f(y,y')$.

Introduce the substituion $y'=v(y)$ $y''=\dfrac{dv}{dy}y'=\dfrac{dv}{dy}v$

Apply this for the original ODE:

$$v'v=f(y,v)$$
$$v'(y)=\frac{f(y,v(y))}{v}=\frac{v^2-2v}{vy}=\frac{v-2}{y}$$

This is a separable ODE. Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Going with your last equation:
I got $y'=c_1y+2$.
Which simplifies to $y=\frac{c_2}{c_1}e^x-2$.
Which is a gorgeous way to solve.
Thank you for the insight.
But how do the solutions compare?
They seem different.
Any thoughts?